# updating view only after changing the size of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, jframe

So I have a JFrame in which inside of it I have a JScrollPane and inside the JScrollPane I have a JPanel. I have a button click mouse listener that modifies the JPanel inside the JScrollPane. The code in the mouse listener is:

```
@Override
    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {

            searchResult.updateInfo();

        }
```

The method updateInfo is adding a bunch of JPanel into the searchResult JPanel. After I click the button associated with this listener, nothing happens, but when I resize the JFrame.. it updates the view.. why is this?

I tried repaint the JFrame, but it did not solve my problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After adding/removing components from a visible GUI you need to tell the panel to layout the components so the preferred size can be recalculated. You need to add:

```
searchResult.revalidate();
searchResult.repaint(); // sometimes needed
```

Then if the preferred size is greater than the size of the scrollpane scrollbars will appear.

Comment: This is because the LayoutManager is only asked upon first rendering about how to layout the components. You have to tell a component to ask the LayoutManager to do this again by calling `revalidate()` as said here.

Answer (score 0):

make 
`searchResult.removeAll();
searchResult.updateInfo();
searchResult.validate();`

if it doesn't work make like this

`searchResult.removeAll();
searchResult.updateInfo();
searchResult.validate();
searchResult.repaint();`

Comment: sorry, I just update my code above.. turns out what I really want in my mouseClicked is just to call updateInfo on searchResult.. this method as I explained above just adds a bunch of panel tp the searchResult JPanel

Comment: no problem , the important thing is u had solve ur problem, good luck.